# Is it possible to prevent Delegate Factory creation in Autofac?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I am updating a library that uses Autofac so that, in addition to the original configuration file (registered via Autofac), it can optionally take a function to accomplish that same goal (again, registered via Autofac).  The original is something like this:

```
public MyClass(ConfigFile config = null)
{
    this._activatorLoader = a => {
        // old config code here...
    }
}
```

The updated version I'd like is:

```
public MyClass(
    Func<Input, IList<Activator>> activatorLoader = null,
    ConfigFile config = null)
{
    if (activatorLoader != null)
    {
        this._activatorLoader = activatorLoader;
    }
    else
    {
        this._activatorLoader = a => {
            // old config code here...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that Autofac is seeing my request for a list of something and always providing the function.  I tried switching to a delegate and get the same problem:

```
public delegate IList<Activator> ActivatorLoader(Input input);

public MyClass(
    ActivatorLoader activatorLoader = null,
    ConfigFile config = null)
{
    if (activatorLoader != null)
    {
        this._activatorLoader = activatorLoader;
    }
    else
    {
        this._activatorLoader = a => {
            // old config code here...
        }
    }
}
```

The loading of the activators must still be delayed, I'd like the flexibility of registering any function based on the situation, and old code (without an activator loader registered) should still work.  Is there any way to prevent Autofac from autogenerating the `Func`?

---

The class will be instantiated through dependency injection in another class.  At a later time, the activator loading code will be triggered (if needed).

```
var myObject = conatiner.Resolve<MyClass>();

// time passes...

myObject.DoActivatorLoading();
```

The primary goal is to prevent Autofac from creating the `Func<Input, IList<Activator>>` if it is not explicitly set.  Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear... you can explain how your `Class` will be instantiated and used and why the loading of the activators should be delayed? But I think you probably need to use `Lazy<T>` so `Lazy<Func<Input, IList<Activator>>> activatorLoader` in this case Autofac will only create the `Func` when you access `activatorLoader.Value`.

Comment: In all cases (Lazy<Func<blabla>> and Func<blabla>), loading of the activators will be delayed, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, it will be easier to create a separate class for activator loading ?

```
public class ActivatorsLoader
{
    public IList<Activator> Load(Input input)
    {
        ///
    }
}

///

public Class(
    ActivatorsLoader activatorsLoader = null,
    ConfigFile config = null)
{
    ///
}
```

But it would be good to see the use cases of your Class.

Comment: I was hoping to solve this problem without creating a separate class or interface.

The two use cases are (1) older code that won't have registered a `Func` and so should use the configuration file (hence the null check in the second and third example) and (2) newer code that will register the `Func` and expect that to be used in place of the configuration file.

Comment: Since I was unable to find a way around this, I'm marking this as the correct answer.